# define routes for directories in public laravel folder

Tags: php, laravel

I have a directory named `fileManager` in `public` laravel folder. now I want to control access it via middlewares So that unsign or not logged users can not access it directly.

By Default any user can type name of directory in browser and navigate to it.
I want to able to define a route like this that can apply and authentication middleware :

```
Route::get('/fileManager', ['middleware' => 'auth', function () {
    //
}]);
```

This is not only, I have many directories in public folder that maybe I want to control users access to those.

How Can I do that ?

Comment: I think you should move those directories to `storage` directory` and send response as per requested. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/filesystem.  I don't think you can restrict access in public folder.

Answer (score 0):

For create middleware create class in the file

*app/http/middleware*

after create

add in array to kernel.php your class

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
            'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
            'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
            'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,

           'newMiddleware' => pahttoclass
        ];
```

Comment: My question is not about Defining Middleware

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to do this Laravel. You can choose anyone you like. But I always use `__construct()` method in each `controller`. Just write this block in controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

It will protect all `methods` only in this `controller` from unauthorized user.

Comment: My question is not about Defining Middleware